# ARkit - placing objects inside the camera filed of view

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, projection-matrix, arkit

I will like to place 2 lines in the bounds of the current camera view as flow:

[image]

Source - SceneKit [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera)

From the ARKit docs, I understand that I need the [projectionMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2887458-projectionmatrix), but how can I calculate the diff from "zNear" to "zFar" and x\y?

I'm starting with this code:

```
let cameraProjectionMatrix = session.currentFrame?.camera.projectionMatrix 
let cameraPosition = SCNVector3.positionFromTransform(cameraProjectionMatrix)
let rightBoxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(...))
rightBoxNode.position = SCNVector3(???)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(rightBoxNode)
```

and for the left one i will probably need

```
var leftPos = rightboxNode.position
leftPos.x = rightboxNode.position.x * -1
leftBoxNode.position = leftPos
```

But I failed when trying calculating rightboxNode.position:

```
rightBoxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: x1 ,y: y1 z: zNear)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SCNSceneRenderer` to unproject the bounds of your screen in the camera space:

```
func renderer(_ sender: SCNSceneRenderer,  updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
  let position = sender.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(0, 0, 0))
  // x, y in screen coordinate space, z in [0, 1] corresponds to [zNear, zFar] in a way that I don't think is proportional
  let node = SCNNode()
  node.position = position
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does it work for using projectionPoint to get 3D point to 2D?